# jQuery remove/hide element

Tags: jquery, html

i have a select tag , when its value changes i want to get some data from database according to that new value , and then put these new data on a new div , this div contains an close sign when user click it , the new div will hide , i did that using jquery , everything is working good except hiding the new div , my jQuery for close the new div was working good , but now no , i don't think that i did wrong in jQuery , but i don't know where is my mistake , would u help me please

## jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#aqIoQuesSelector").on("change",function(){
        var IO = $("#aqIoQuesSelector").val();
        $("#aqSugInfo").html('<div class="closeSign1"></div>');
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/giveContenfForIO/"+IO+"/TRUE",function(data){
            if(data.length>0){
                $("#aqSugInfo").css("text-align","right");
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    $("#aqSugInfo").append('<p><span class="aqoneContenSug">'+data[i]+'</span></p>');
                }
            }else{
                $("#aqSugInfo").append('<span class="successMessage">no suggesiont</span>');
            }
            $("#aqSugInfo").css("display","block");
        }); 
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.closeSign1').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

$html code#

```
<div id="addQuestion1" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="Paragraph">Question</label>
            <p>
                <label>Text</label>
                <input id="aqQuestionText"type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Answer</label>
                <input id="aqQuestionAnswer"type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Is Existed ?</label>
                <input type="button" value="check" class="button1" id="aqQuestionSug"/>
            </p>
            <div id="aqSugQues" class="SuggestionsContainer">
                <div class="closeSign1"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p><label class="Paragraph">Choices</label></p>
            <p>
                <label>First Choice</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1" name="choice1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Second Choice</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1" name="choice2"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Third Choice</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1" name="choice3"/>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li id="aqQuestionIoli">
            <label class="Paragraph">Question IO</label>
            <p>
                <label>Concept</label>
                <select class="ConceptSelector1"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>IO</label>
                <select id="aqIoQuesSelector"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Info</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            </p>
            <div id="aqSugInfo" class="SuggestionsContainer">
                <div class="closeSign1"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="aqAnswerIoli">
            <label class="Paragraph">Answer IO</label>
            <p>
                <label>Concept</label>
                <select class="ConceptSelector1"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>IO</label>
                <select id="aqIoAnswerSelector"></select>
            </p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="Paragraph">Hints</label>
            <p>
                <label>First Hint</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Second Hint</label>
                <input type="text" class="longInput1"/>
            </p>
            <div id="aqSugHints" class="SuggestionsContainer">
                <div class="closeSign1"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Type</label>
            <select class="TypeSelector"></select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="save" class="button1"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

notice that the sign close is used three time here , it works for the first time at the div `aqSugQues` , but doesn't work at the div `aqSugInfo` nor the div `aqSugHints`

the ajax is working good and i print the results

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#aqSugInfo").html('<div class="closeSign1"></div>');
```

is replacing the contents of the div with a new button that doesn't have the click-event bound, so every time you update, that button will lose its binding.

You might try wrapping your dynamic content in a container that you can easily remove, or do something like

```
$("#aqSugInfo").children(':not(.closeSign1)').remove();
```

Comment: that line is the close sign  , and its class is `closeSign1` and the jQuery function is about the same class , and way i will try your code

Comment: you the one man , it works , really thank you for helping , and thank you for descriping what happens , i will accept answer

Answer (score 1):

If it's `$("#aqSugInfo")` you want to hide, why not say so in the code? `$("#aqSugInfo").hide();`?

Comment: because i want to reduce the size of my code , so i will have one function for hiding all the new div , and that function is (.closeSign1) , and it works for the first Div , but not for the second and third div

Comment: Since you're re-using the same `aqSugInfo` div anyway, what's the overhead? Did you try to see my suggestion to see if it worked?

Comment: i know it will work , but you wrong i didn't use the save `aqSugInfo` , check the code , this is ad ID

Comment: no no not the same id , check the html, it is not the same id, any way thank you for helping , and see the above answer it works with me , thank you for helping